# R Shiny `options(shiny.autoreload = TRUE)` doesn't work with change in a module script

Tags: r, shiny

I am running a Shiny app as a background (local) job by sourcing a `run_app.R` file which looks like this:

```r
# Run app as a background local job
options(shiny.autoreload = TRUE)
shiny::runApp()
```

Running this script as a local job allows me to make changes to the app code (server.R or ui.R) and the app reloads automatically in a browser window. However, if I change one of the module files (I have a modularised app), the browser refreshes, but the app doesn't change.

Does anyone have a tip on how to make Shiny autoreload with changes to any app file (not only server.R and ui.R)?

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/2711) you can find the according GitHub issue.

Comment: Thanks @ismirsehregal - I can then probably assume that until this gets resolved I can't expect a decent solution...